# Is there an alternative to \ref or \eqref that omits the chapter number without changing the overall behaviour?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I am using a thesis template from my university (memoir class) which by default appends the chapter number when I use `\ref` and `\eqref`, which is totally fine by me.

But in some occasions I want to omit it. For example, when referencing multiple equations, I would like to produce something like:

> Equations (2.5,7) can then be rewritten as...

I know you can do something similar for `\cite` (citing only the publication's year or author, for example), but I can't find a similar technique for `\ref` or `\eqref`.

I've seen other posts that deal with this issue, but on a document-wide level, which I don't want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strip out the chapter number using the technique below in `\getref`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,refcount}

\makeatletter
\def\@getref#1.#2{#2}
\newcommand{\getref}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\@getref\getrefnumber{#1}}\x}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\setcounter{section}{3}% Just for this example
\section{A section}\label{sec:section}

See~\eqref{eqn:equation1} and~\eqref{eqn:equation2} in Section~\ref{sec:section}.
\setcounter{equation}{12}% Just for this example
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \label{eqn:equation1}
\end{equation}

See~(\ref{eqn:equation1}, \getref{eqn:equation2}) in Section~\getref{sec:section}.
\setcounter{equation}{17}% Just for this example
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \label{eqn:equation2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

---

With the addition of [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), you can use `\hgetref`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,refcount,hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\@getref#1.#2{#2}
\newcommand{\getref}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\@getref\getrefnumber{#1}}\x}
\newcommand{\hgetref}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{\getref{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\setcounter{section}{3}% Just for this example
\section{A section}\label{sec:section}

See~\eqref{eqn:equation1} and~\eqref{eqn:equation2} in Section~\ref{sec:section}.
\setcounter{equation}{12}% Just for this example
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \label{eqn:equation1}
\end{equation}

See~(\ref{eqn:equation1}, \hgetref{eqn:equation2}) in Section~\hgetref{sec:section}.
\setcounter{equation}{17}% Just for this example
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \label{eqn:equation2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. It is not producing a hyperlink, if that's what you mean, but I'm not worried about that.

Comment: Just a quick question about \hgetref - is it supposed to work inside captions? I had to use it for the first time in a Figure caption and I'm getting "undefined sequence" errors. It produces the desired output, but the error doesn't go away even after successive builds.